# Someone from old job asking for payroll refund in cash - is this a scam?

Tags: salary, payroll

i worked a job for a special event was given a total of 3 checks. i deposited them all fine and then was told 2 weeks later that the second check was a duplicate to the first and they now want me to refund the amount of that check in cash to the store. i have not been contacted by the GM or the companies accountant another employee. what should i do?

Comment: Was it a duplicate or was it pay for a different work period?

Comment: Did you check their math?

Comment: Was the second check actually an exact duplicate? If your manager isn't the one contacting you, who is asking you to do this?

Comment: Were you actually overpaid?

Comment: This sounds like a scam to me. I have come across situations where I was paid a (genuine) "duplicate" payment a couple of times (due to a mistake in payroll or something like that) but in those cases I was asked (By an actual manager, or an accountant/HR!) to pay the money back via a bank transfer. Legit employers don't do anything in cash like this. Do the 3 checks cover the amount you should have been paid for working at that event or have you been given a 'duplicate' payment?

Comment: btw, checks can "bounce" a surprisingly long time after they have seemingly been deposited fine ! (i.e. don't assume just because you deposited it at you bank, it has cleared. I like gnasher729's answer in this respect.)

Comment: @JoeStrazzere, there is not a competent accountant anywhere on the planet who would accept or allow a cash refund under these circumstances.  It is too easy for cash to grow legs and go walkabout.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere The accountant will have no problem at all accepting a check, or a cashier's check, *IF* this is legitimate.  The other circumstances suggest it may be a scam.  At the very least, the OP should contact the company GM and head accountant about the matter.

Comment: The biggest issue I see here is tax reporting to the IRS. If your employer will be filing a W2 or 1099 to show that they paid you, what will that reflect? If it reflects the full amount (including the duplicate check) and you pay back in cash, you have no guarantee that your salary will be represented correctly come tax time - which might mean you are still responsible for taxes on the amount you paid back.

Answer (score 30):

If this was a one-time job then there is a good chance that this is a scam. They gave you three checks. When you send cash back, you’ll find that shortly afterwards all three checks bounce.

It’s also possibly a rogue employee. The company pays three checks, you pay cash back and the rogue employee puts it in his pocket. Paying by check and asking for cash back is the mother of all red flags  .

At the very least you should contact a different person in accounting to verify this story.

Comment: Yes, this. Go to the personal finance (Money SE) and look up overpayment scams. There is a question on that every week it seems.  The only difference is that those are usually online or remote.  .

Comment: "Paying by check and asking for cash back is the mother of all red flags." -- Words to live by.

Answer (score 10):

Who were you contacted by? Do they have the authority to make such a request? Did you reach out to management or HR at the company to discuss this with them?

If it were me, I'd contact someone at the company who has the authority to make this request and I would get the request in writing on company letterhead... then I'd consult an attorney before doing anything else.

Comment: I wouldn't give them "cash" I would give them a check for the exact amount, and in the memo, state the purpose. **The memo is the best method to provide a binding reason for the check itself.**  This is, of course, you agree with the determination that the check is indeed results in an overpayment.

Comment: I would also actually work out if it was indeed an overpayment - there may be time worked that the person requesting this is not aware of, or the amount itself might be slightly wrong.

Comment: Definitely get an official request in writing.  At the very least you need a way to prove that you didn't get paid this money if the IRS comes knocking on your door.  I'd ask for the written request to include details, for both the original check and the duplicate, including dates, amounts and a clear statement that the second check is a duplicate of the, so you are being requested to refund the money to the company.  Add to that a memo on the check that you write, and you should be good.  I'd only get an attorney involved if they balk.

Answer (score 8):

It's a scam.

1. **Completely ignore** this absurd 'request' until you literally hear from the **owner** (ie you physically talk with the owner, ideally in person not on the phone).

Do not even reply, until you hear from the owner.

## IF ..

**IF** anything ever comes of this...

2. Do NOTHING, NOTHING until you get a request in writing. It must be **printed paper, signed and dated by the owner. And it must be handed to you in person by the owner.**

## IF ..

**IF** anything ever comes of that...

3. regarding handing them literally cash - ROFL - write a check
4. Have them write out on paper a receipt that you handed them a check

Answer (score 0):

I certainly would call the company to let them know what is happening.  It does sound like a scam to me, and they might not know about it.

If they paid you money and you accepted it in good faith, believing this to be the agreed-upon remuneration, you are entitled to cash it and keep it.  If they made a mistake, the mistake is theirs. **Especially** if you were an *employee* and this is a *salary* check.

Comment: "If they paid you money and you accepted it in good faith, believing this to be the agreed-upon remuneration, you are entitled to cash it and keep it. " That's dangerously false. In many jurisdictions, you do have to return overpaid remuneration, even if you acted in good faith. That very much depends on the details. That said, OP's situation is probaby a scam, as explained in other answers.